# Calculate sin(x) as the form of series in c++

Tags: c++

We know that
   sin(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+x^9/9! and so on. I have written this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

const int m=19;

int factorial(int n) {

    if (n==0){ return 1;}
    return n*factorial(n-1);
}

int main() {
   float x;
   cin >> x;

   float sum=0;
   int k=1;
   for (int i=1;i<=m;i+=2) {
      sum+=(k*(powf(x,i)/factorial(i)));
      k=k*(-1);
   }

   cout<<"series sum is equal :"<<sum<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

One problem is that when I enter x=3 it gives me -10.9136, but I know that values range of sin(x) is [-1, 1] what is problem? Please help me.

Comment: You could try formatting your code a little better - it may not fix the bug but it should make it a little easier to spot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're running out of precision due to destructive cancellation.

You have an alternating series where some of the terms get very large. But those terms cancel each other out to a small result. Since `float` has limited precision, your round off error is larger than your final value.

You can "reduce" the problem by using double-precision. But it won't go away. Standard implementations of `sin/cos` involve taking the modulo of the argument by `2 pi` to make it small.

**EDIT :**

**I found the other problem.** You have an integer overflow in your factorial function when `i = 19`.

Comment: so one solution is that use double or  int?

Comment: The standard solution is to reduce the argument so that it's between `-pi` and `pi`.

Comment: Actually, I think there's more going than just destructive cancellation. The argument of `3` shouldn't be large enough make the answer that inaccurate. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @user466534: I just updated my answer with the other problem I found.

Comment: Also for the sake of both efficiency and accuracy you shouldn't be evaluating the power and factorial terms for every iteration - hint: think about the relationship between successive terms...

Comment: it surprised me how  you found it in a few  minute,thanks   very much @Mysticial ,i have accept your answer right now,thanks ones again,so other  code part is correct is?i mean calculation method,thanks ones again

Comment: The method is correct for small values of `x`. For large values, the destructive cancellation thing will still be a problem. Try it and you'll see. If you print out each individual term and know that float has only 6 - 7 digits of precision, you'll see why.

Comment: so after that i will use double or long type

Comment: Throwing more precision at it will only "delay" the problem to larger x. The full-proof method is just to do `x %= 2 * PI` before you start the algorithm. (You can get Pi either from the C-library or just hard-code it.)

Comment: aa and one more question does  compiler do  %  operator  with float type?

Comment: Nevermind that. I guess % doesn't work on floats. Use `x = fmod(x,2*Pi);`.

Comment: ok thanks @Mysticial  now i dont worry about precisions  or something like this because i need it for university exam where  important is just showing your working,so thanks ones again, after  exam i  return back this problem and will try to find   solve these problems for large value of x .